# Error in loading data in Redis From YCSB

Tags: redis, ycsb

I am Trying to load data in redis server from ycsb load data command. It is working Fine with 1 Million records but when am trying to load more data like 250 million records then it is running for some time and after that it show error in loading by giving following exception. Can anybody suggest where am going wrong ?

Am getting following error :

redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:74)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:122)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:178)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.zadd(Jedis.java:1448)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.RedisClient.insert(RedisClient.java:97)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.insert(DBWrapper.java:148)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload.doInsert(CoreWorkload.java:461)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:269)

Thanks

Comment: You should post the relevant extract of your code to expect some help.

Comment: [link]https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/master/redis/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/db/RedisClient.java This is where you can find the client code for redis which YCSB uses for loading and running the workloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is a timeout. It's not surprising considering the huge workload you defined.

You could try to modify the way YCSB connects to Redis, to add a longer timeout than the default one.

In com.yahoo.ycsb.db.RedisClient, replace

```
jedis = new Jedis(host, port);
```

with

```
jedis = new Jedis(host, port, TIMEOUT);
```

With TIMEOUT being an integer. The default value in Jedis is 2000, which I assume means 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanks alot it Solved My Problem I made changes in the Redis Client n I was good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

There is redis.timeout paramater, try to pass, for example, -p redis.timeout=10000